# Jquery mobile tap on stacked elements

Tags: jquery, events, web-applications, mobile, tap

I'm making a webapp with a similar navigation structure as the facebook app/webapp.

My problem is, that when i tap on my "show menu" button, I also tap on my menu items behind it.

my HTML structure is something like this:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="page.html">Menu item</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="contentholder">
  <div id="menu-btn"></div>
</div>
```

#menu and #contentholder are placed on top of each other with position:absolute;top:0;left:0;

I use Jquery mobile for touch events.

My tap script is as follows:

```
$('body').on('tap', '#menu-btn', menuActive);
```

I tried e.stopPropagation() in the menuActive function, but that didn't seem to do anything good.

The menuActive function:

```
function menuActive(e){
  $('#menu-btn').addClass('active');
  $('#contentholder').addClass('slided');
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is your `menuActive` function? Provide a sample.

Comment: I added it to the question. But it doesn't do much, its a visual function

Comment: The `event.stopPropagation` probably won't work on IE. Did you test it in IE? Try adding `e.stopPropagatation` at the top of the function and see if it works on FF, Chrome.

Comment: Yes I already tried, and it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with e.preventDefault() in my menuActive function. Although I can't understand why it taps through my #contentholder... Oh well, now it works...

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to answer and not link to the information but I cannot find where I read it.

In summary, the 'tap' event is to replace 'click' because 'click' waits too many milliseconds to know if it was a click or another event.

Because it is so short, it should not be used when it causes something to move. This is because the 'click' or 'tap' will then register still at that X and Y and click the region which is now exposed.

It seems that you found a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the info, its good knowledge. Should vclick be used instead if you are activating moving objects?